# Using Func with Task in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm having some problems trying to understand how exactly `Func` works in C#, despite having read a handful og good blogposts about it.

I have the following scenario:
I'm building a small billing system which uses the Azure Service Bus queue to process billings. There's two processes that can be initialized by the user:

1. Create a daybook for checking that the transactions are correct before
2. creating the actual invoice for the customer

For this, I've made a general method which initializes a billing task (containing N billings) which takes a `bool` parameter to tell if it's a daybook or actual billings that needs to be created. Inside this method, I'm running the following check:

```
if (isDayBookProcessing)
{
    // Daybook processing code here   
}
else
{
    // Run queue process async
    StartQueueProcess(queueName, billingTaskId, numOfItemsEnqueued);
}
```

I've then got a general "StartQueueProcess" method, which is run in it's own `Task` like this:

```
private void StartQueueProcess(string queueName, int billingTaskId, int numOfItemsEnqueued)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _factory.AzureFactory.ServiceBus.ProcessBillingQueue(queueName, billingTaskId, numOfItemsEnqueued));
}
```

As you can see, the `StartQueueProcess` method runs the `ProcessBillingQueue` method on m y `ServiceBus`class, which means that it can't run a `ProcessDaybookQueue`

What I initially thought was to just make use of `Func<string, int, int, bool>` and make `StartQueueProcess`method return a bool (since `Func` needs to return something) making it look like this:

```
if (isDayBookProcessing)
{
    // Daybook processing code here 
    StartQueueProcess(_factory.AzureFactory.ServiceBus.ProcessDaybookQueue(queueName, billingTaskId, numOfItemsEnqueued));  
}
else
{
    // Run queue process async   
    StartQueueProcess(_factory.AzureFactory.ServiceBus.ProcessBillingQueue(queueName, billingTaskId, numOfItemsEnqueued));
}

private bool StartQueueProcess(Func<string, int, int, bool> processMethod)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processMethod);

    return true;
}
```

However, this gives an error telling me that `Argument type 'void' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Func<string, int, int bool>'`

My `_factory.AzureFactory.ServiceBus.ProcessDaybookQueue(queueName, billingTaskId, numOfItemsEnqueued)` returns void. Making it return `Func<string, int, int, bool>` gives no errors. But why exactly? Shouldn't I be able to make it return what I want (i.e. void)?

Can anyone shed some light on this? :-)

Comment: Great article on this topic : http://goo.gl/gWgzPP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `Func`, you need an `Action`. A `Func` is when your delegate has a return value. An `Action` is fit when there is no return value:

```
private void StartQueueProcess(Action<string, int, int> processMethod)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processMethod);
}
```

Note, that wrapping [async over sync is an anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). You're better off using `Task.Run` at the call-site instead:

```
if (isDayBookProcessing)
{
    // Daybook processing code here 
    Task.Run(() => _factory.AzureFactory.ServiceBus.ProcessDaybookQueue(
                           queueName, 
                           billingTaskId, 
                           numOfItemsEnqueued));  
}
else
{
    // Run queue process async   
    Task.Run(() => _factory.AzureFactory.ServiceBus.ProcessBillingQueue(
                           queueName,
                           billingTaskId, 
                           numOfItemsEnqueued));
}
```

Although I see you're invoking the same method, so I don't see the need for an `if-else`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yuval, that's definitely more simple than my approach :-) I do need the `if-else` since there's different logic going on in the ServiceBus methods.

Answer (score 0):

I see two separate issues:
1. I am afraid that `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processMethod)` won't do what you expect it to do. It will not execute `processMethod`.
2. `StartQueueProcess` is defined to accept a Func<> function with three parameters. It says nothing about parameters themselves. It's your responsibility supply this lambda with some parameters.

Why do you make an assumption that you need to use `Func<>` here? You don't have to. Your `StartQueueProcess` can like like this:

```
private bool StartQueueProcess(
     string param1, 
     int param2, 
     int param3, 
     Action<string, int, int> processMethod)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processMethod(param1, param2, param3));
}
```

E.g. this [StartNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) overload will happily accept any Action parameter).

Moreover, in this particular case I don't see need to declare a new function at all. A simple `.StartNew` call will probably do just fine (it's close though):

```
if (isDayBookProcessing)
{
    // Daybook processing code here 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  _factory
        .AzureFactory
        .ServiceBus
        .ProcessDaybookQueue(queueName, billingTaskId, numOfItemsEnqueued));  
}
else
{
    // Run queue process async   
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _factory
        .AzureFactory
        .ServiceBus
        .ProcessBillingQueue(queueName, billingTaskId, numOfItemsEnqueued));
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your answer! :-) Appreciated! I guess what I missed was the parameters, I thought parameters were passed automatically (somehow) by including them in the calling method (see my original post code). I went with the code Yuval wrote, which does the job as it should. Utilising a `Func` for this was just out of pure curiousness and trying to learn something new ;-)